# Проблема с отправками данных на сервер Node.js!

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Я делаю веб проект на JS с использование Node.js. С веб у меня только первый опыт и у меня есть некоторые проблемы. Облазил весь интернет, решения не нашёл. Так вот, у меня есть html документ c оформлением, в котором есть кнопки(button) и формы(input), и js документ с сервером на Node js, на нём есть их обработчик. Подскажите как я переслать данные на сервер?
Вот пример html:

```
<button type="button" id="Name">Имя:</button>
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" name="Input">
</form>
```

Вот пример js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch - читайте

Comment: Спасибо конечно за статью, но мне же ещё как-то нужно считывать запрос на сервере. В по вашей ссылке в статье нету примера обработки.

Comment: В Вашем вопросе, не сказано, что у Вас есть проблемы с получением данных. Сказано только об отсутствии знаний в отправке